# how to ignore tashkeel character counting in text wrapping in corona sdk?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I'm doing text wrapping (to separate long string into lines) in corona

```
function wrap(str, limit, indent, indent1)
  indent = indent or ""
  indent1 = indent1 or indent
  limit = limit or 72
  local here = 1-#indent1

  str = replacePartOfString(str,"*","\n")

  return indent1..str:gsub("(%s+)()(%S+)()",
                          function(sp, st, word, fi)
                            if fi-here > limit then
                              here = st - #indent
                              return "\n"..indent..word
                            end
                          end)
end

local someString = " This is intended for strings without newlines in them (i.e. after reflowing the text and breaking it into paragraphs.)  This is intended for strings without newlines in them (i.e. after reflowing the text and breaking it into paragraphs.)  This is intended for strings without newlines in them (i.e. after reflowing the text and breaking it into paragraphs.)  This is intended for strings without newlines in them (i.e. after reflowing the text and breaking it into paragraphs.) "

print_r(string.split(wrap(someString,70,"",""),"\n"))
```

it works fine with english and arabic, but the only problem is it counts the tashkeel in arabic as letters, what is the best way to ignore these characters and not count them? I want to keep them, but not count them in text wrapping.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.gsub()` works on the *bytes* of a string, not on its *chars*. There is a difference when the string contains Unicode text.
Use the `utf8` library to get the chars.

Comment: an external library? or the default utf8 lua library, any example?

Comment: The problem described by OP is not UTF-8 specific.  For example, in 1-byte encoding win1256 tashkeels are also encoded by separate codes as if they were standalone symbols.

Comment: I ended up making my own wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

the unicode id for the tashkeel in arabic language is:

```
[\x{064B}-\x{0650}],[\x{0618}-\x{061A}],[\x{0652}-\x{0653}],[\x{0652}-\x{0653}]
```

you can used any code remove it.

Regard